# Distinct character SET of substring in string

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose a SET is all distinct character in a string.
I need to find out count of such distinct SET  made from substrings in a string.

2 SETS are same when they have same characters in them.

eg:-string=ABBC

answer=6

distinct character sets of substrings are:{A},{B},{C},{A,B},{A,B,C},{B,C}

Note:Substring BBC and BC have same SET {B,C}, ABBC substring is SET {A,B,C}

PS:Seen on hackerearth Augito backend contest.The contest is over on 30-05-2021

Constraint 1<=Stringlen<=10^5 so expected complexity is O(N) or O(NLOGN)

Comment: So what's your question?  Where do you get stuck?  It seems to be a Power set problem.

Comment: Power set.!! never seem to have come across it..Can you please send a reference program..need complexity within O(n) or O(nlogn)

Comment: Can you please include the original Problem source to make it clear?   In your PO (A,C) is missing?

Comment: AC is not valid as there is no substring which will give you AC as set.Substring starting from A are A-->{A},ABC-->{A,B,C},ABBC-->{A,B,C}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two pointer approach + counting the frequencies.

```java
static int countSub(String str)
{
    int n = (int)str.length();

    // Stores the count of
    // subStrings
    int ans = 0;

    // Stores the frequency
    // of characters
    int []cnt = new int[26];

    // Initialised both pointers
    // to beginning of the String
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (i < n)
    {

        // If all characters in
        // subString from index i
        // to j are distinct
        if (j < n &&
        (cnt[str.charAt(j) - 'a'] == 0))
        {

            // Increment count of j-th
            // character
            cnt[str.charAt(j) - 'a']++;

            // Add all subString ending
            // at j and starting at any
            // index between i and j
            // to the answer
            ans += (j - i + 1);

            // Increment 2nd pointer
            j++;
        }

        // If some characters are repeated
        // or j pointer has reached to end
        else
        {

            // Decrement count of j-th
            // character
            cnt[str.charAt(i) - 'a']--;

            // Increment first pointer
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Return the final
    // count of subStrings
    return ans;
}
```

Here it considered only lower case letters. You can refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-substrings-having-all-distinct-characters)

Comment: I dont think this would help; for input bcb answer is 3 (b)(c)(bc) basically unique sets that can be formed from substring of string.